# Connect one chat headset to 4 PCs for meetings

Tags: audio

I need to connect one chat headset (speakers and mic) to 4 different PCs simultaneously so I can hear audio signal coming from either one of those PCs (with volume control) and use my mic to send signal to all of the PCs. I will need a mixer (software or hardware) so that I can use to mute/unmute my mic signal on any PC.

Anyone have any suggestions? Best (potential) solution I found is the mixer linked below but it has terrible reviews. Is there a better way to do this? If I plug in 4 USB sound cards to a PC, is there a software i can use to achieve same results?

8 Channels Input and 2 Channels Output Metal Mono Stereo Audio Sound Mixer with Power Adapter
https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B07RK5SH2V/ref=cm_sw_r_apan_i_YYJ16D5FX43PKSDNTPS5

Comment: At the music school, we have just that, although I do not know the model name of that. I will ask my teacher about it. (It's a mixing panel that supports both Jack inputs and XLR, Jack can be used with computers)

Comment: Thanks. I think a diy active mixer would be a solution. Or two 4 channel mixers.